# $h^{0, 1}$ of K3 surface (a priori non-Kahler)

Tags: complex-geometry, spectral-sequences, hodge-theory, k3-surfaces

I am trying to understand paper by Siu "Every K3 surface is Kahler". Let $M$ be a K3 surface.

Siu wrote $H^1 ( M , \mathscr{O}_M ) =0$ without any references. It is written on fifth page. Maybe I missed something, but it seems unlikely.

**Question** Why $H^1 ( M , \mathscr{O}_M ) =0$ ?

**Comment 1**  Siu defines K3 surface as "simply connected compact manifold of complex dimension two whose canonical line bundle is trivial".

**Comment 2** *Why is not it obvious?* Assertion would be quite clear if we already knew that $M$ is Kahler. What we actually need to know is that Frölicher spectral sequence degenerates. Indeed, "simply connected" implies $H^1( M , \mathbb{C} ) = 0$.

I want to emphasise, that the purpose of this paper is to prove, that K3 surfaces are Kahler. Therefore, we must not use assumption that $M$ is Kahler.

Comment: You have already answered your questions. because$H^1(M,\mathbb{C})$=$h^{1,0}+h^{0,1}$=0, thus $h^{0,1}=0$

Comment: The point is that you can show (without assuming Kähler) that on a compact surface, any holomorphic $1$-form is $d$-closed, so $H^{1,0}(M)$ injects into $H^1_{\text{dR}}(M)$.

Comment: @Feng Hao You used Hodge decomposition. The existence of such decomposition is what my question is about. I knew only that such decomposition exists for Kahler manifolds (it is not obvious).

Comment: @Ted Shifrin It is equivalent to show that any exact (1,1) form is actually 0. I thought about it, and I am stuck. I tried to consider $\int \omega \wedge \bar \omega$. But I do not see why it has to be non zero. The same trick works perfectly for (2, 0) forms. Give me a hint.

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry I slip my mind. nice strategy  for you guys. I mean injectivity

Comment: I think you were on the right track. Suppose $\alpha$ is a holomorphic $1$-form. Consider $\int_M d\alpha\wedge\overline{d\alpha}$.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin I expected to use argument that this integral is positive. But if $\alpha = a   z_1 \ d \bar z_1 + b  z_2 \ d \bar z_2$. Then $d\alpha \wedge \overline{d \alpha } = -( a \bar b + \bar a b ) d z_1 \wedge d \bar z_1 \wedge dz_2 \wedge d \bar z_2$. The coefficient may have different signs depending on $a$ and $b$. So I can not prove that the integral is not 0.

Comment: I said $\alpha$ was a $\bar\partial$-closed $(1,0)$-form!

Comment: @Ted Shifrin I realize, that I may be confused about indexes. My initial question is about $H^1( \mathscr{O}_M ) = H^{0 , 1}$. So I need to consider (0,1) form wich is $\bar \partial$ closed. You suggested to consider $(1, 0)$ form. How does it help to answer initial question?

Comment: No, you're right about the indices, but my original comment was about $H^{1,0}(M)$. Indeed, following my path shows that $h^{1,0}=0$, but doesn't restrict $h^{0,1}$. The sheaf exact sequence $0\to\Bbb C\to\mathcal O\to d\mathcal O\to 0$, in fact, shows that $h^{0,1}\ge \frac12b_1$.

Comment: Note, by the way, that your title was referring to $h^{1,0}$, so I'm not totally to blame here. You might check out references in [this MathOverflow question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/25723/dolbeault-cohomology-of-hopf-manifolds).

Comment: @Ted Shifrin Thanks. I edited the title.